# Embed wxmplot window in wxpython frame

Tags: wxpython

Is it possible to embed the wxm multiplot window in a wx main frame? 
This site ( http://newville.github.io/wxmplot/other.html#multiplotframe ) gives details about how to get a multiplot but the plot is displayed as separate window. I want to create a GUI with wx widgets but I am unable to put them all in the same window frame.

Answer (score 0):

Well, MultiPlotFrame is a frame that contains some PlotPanels, so you can't do it directly, but look as the source code of multiframe

https://github.com/newville/wxmplot/blob/master/lib/multiframe.py

I guess you can pretty much take it almost as it is and turn it into something like MultiPlotPanel, and use that in your frame.